# Custom Offline Fallback Page with create-react-app and workbox-webpack-plugin

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox-webpack-plugin

I need a custom-offline-page to be shown everytime I am offline irrespective of the precached data.

I am using `create-react-app` and `workbox-webpack-plugin`

I tried changing `NavigationFallback` to `offline.html` but everytime I reload the page when offline it displays the `index.html` page and does not show `offline.html`.

Can someone help me adding custom offline fallback page?

package.json

```
below is my package.json screenshot
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
"availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.2.1",
"aws-amplify": "^1.1.6",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"axios-mock-adapter": "^1.15.0",
"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
"babel-jest": "23.6.0",
"babel-loader": "8.0.4",
"babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.2",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^5.0.3",
"bfj": "6.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"chalk": "2.4.1",
"classnames": "^2.2.6",
"css-loader": "1.0.0",
"dotenv": "6.0.0",
"dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
"eslint": "5.6.0",
"eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.3",
"eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
"file-loader": "2.0.0",
"firebase": "^5.5.3",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"fs-extra": "7.0.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
"identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
"jest": "23.6.0",
"jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
"jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"object-assign": "^4.1.1",
"offline-js": "^0.7.19",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
"pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
"postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
"postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
"postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
"prop-types": "^15.6.2",
"qrcode.react": "^0.8.0",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
"react-dev-utils": "^6.0.4",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"react-multistep": "^3.2.3",
"react-overlay-loader": "0.0.3",
"react-plx": "^1.3.9",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-config": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
"react-seo": "^1.0.11",
"react-share": "^2.3.1",
"react-telephone-input": "^4.73.2",
"react-toastify": "^4.3.2",
"reactstrap": "^6.4.0",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"resolve": "1.8.1",
"sass-loader": "7.1.0",
"serve": "^10.0.2",
"style-loader": "0.23.0",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
"url-loader": "1.1.1",
"webpack": "4.19.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.2"
```

}

Comment: How are you setting NavigationFallback? also, can you please post your package.json to see the versions of your packages?

Comment: @c-chavez I am using the below code in my custom service worker to add navigation fallback
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/offline.html');

added the package.json screenshot in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [`navigateFallback`](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache) property to pre-cached the data, here is the documentation on how to used it:

**`sw-precache`**

> **navigateFallback** [String] Sets an HTML document to use as a fallback
>   for URLs not found in the sw-precache cache. This fallback URL needs
>   to be cached via `staticFileGlobs` or `dynamicUrlToDependencies` otherwise
>   it won't work.
>
> ```
> // via staticFileGlobs
> staticFileGlobs: ['/shell.html']
> navigateFallback: '/shell.html'
>
> // via dynamicUrlToDependencies
> dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
>   '/shell': ['/shell.hbs']
> },
> navigateFallback: '/shell'
> ```
>
> This comes in handy when used with a web application that performs
>   client-side URL routing using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History). It allows any arbitrary
>   URL that the client generates to map to a fallback cached HTML entry.
>   This fallback entry ideally should serve as an "application shell"
>   that is able to load the appropriate resources client-side, based on
>   the request URL.
>
> Note: This is not intended to be used to route failed navigations to a
>   generic "offline fallback" page. The navigateFallback page is used
>   whether the browser is online or offline. If you want to implement an
>   "offline fallback", then using an approach similar to this [example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/) is
>   more appropriate.
>
> Default: ""